# Can't cd into my public folder that is inside my server directory

Tags: reactjs, powershell, server-side-rendering

I've created an fullstack mern stack app, and now that i want to deploy my app, i'm doing the ssr. for this i've added this script into the root

```
 "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd server && npm install && cd ../client && npm install",
    "deploy": "set BUILD_PATH=../server/public && npm run build --prefix client && npm start --prefix server ",
    "deploy-cluster": "npm run build --prefix client && npm run cluster --prefix server",
    "server": "npm run watch --prefix server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

this create a public folder in my server folder, and it works fine but for some reason the public folder its ignore by the server and i cant even cd into it [as yoy can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scxN3.png) I get all the permissions so I have no clue to what can be going on

Comment: How did you create the public folder? Try opening that folder in the file explorer, then copy the path from the location bar of the explorer window. Or try `cd pub` and then hit the TAB key and see what happens. You probably have some whitespace in the name

Comment: The folder was created with the deploy action in the script, and you were right it was a whitespace thanks